# Program will sometimes crash

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, error-handling, crash

I have a windows form that is currently getting data from a serial port and obtaining data. The at intervals the data is saved in an xml and after saved into an sql. The program works sometimes and just crashes at other times. Here is an event log of the error.

```
Application: appname
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TimeoutException
Stack:
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.ReadTo(System.String)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.ReadLine()
   at appname.frmParameters.mySerialPort_DataReceived(System.Object, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.CatchReceivedEvents(System.Object, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream+EventLoopRunner.CallReceiveEvents(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Would appreciate any help thanks

Comment: We need the piece of source code where the program crashes. It would be appreciate if you also put in the description the message of the error(For example if your Exception is called e you have to add e.Message,e.Source and e.StackTrace

Comment: In my current circumstance, i'm unable to pinpoint the error location as this event failure error is from the compiled .exe. Is there an overall wrap command that I could use to output the error into a log file? I'm unable to run it from the source code and would require to compile it to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a timeoutexception on the ReadTo(string) method, so you should catch and handle that.

```
try
{
    Readto(string);
}
catch(TimeoutException ex)
{
    //Handle the timeout exception
}
```

Comment: will do this for now and update when i get an exeption. Unable to replicate the error now,

Comment: It should be fairly easy to replicate - TimeoutException is thrown when there's no data available on the serial port. So stop the other side of the COM port from sending data and you should get your TimeoutException.